# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’. I am getting this error whileinstalling HElib-master

Tags: gcc

I installed `gcc 4.6.3`  Please help me to solve this problem.
First I configured the `GMP` and next configured `NTL`, but while building `HElib` I am getting this error. when I type the make command it showing error as:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option -std=c++11
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? How did you install GCC and exactly what steps did you follow to build HElib? Are you working from directions that are available online, and if so can you provide a link? Are you specifically trying to use gcc 4.6.3? Would a later version be sufficient? Is that the version provided by the Ubuntu release that you are using? Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: What version does `g++ -version` report?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 12 version , i followed the steps given in this link to build HElib::    https://github.com/shaih/HElib

Answer (score 4):

GCC 4.6.x pre-dates support for the C++11 standard so does not provide
`-std=c++11`. It anticpates C++11 experimentally and provides `-std=c++0x`
to enable that experimental support. `-std=c++11` is first available in
GCC 4.7.x. If you cannot upgrade to a more recent compiler then change
`-std=c++11` to `-std=c++0x`.

**Contd. for OP's comments**

Perhaps you have not read the `INSTALL.TXT` file of the [`HELib`](https://github.com/shaih/HElib) package?
Specfically:

> Before building HElib, you may want to look at the Makefile, and
>   consider adjusting some of the defaults for CC and CFLAGS. The
>   defaults should be OK on most systems, but you can see the suggested
>   options, which are documented in the Makefile.

Following this advice, edit `src/Makefile`, find:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -std=c++11 -pthread -DFHE_THREADS -DFHE_DCRT_THREADS -DFHE_BOOT_THREADS
```

and change `-std=c++11` to `-std=c++0x`.

Be aware that the project is not guaranteed to build successfully with gcc 4.6.3
- a very old compiler version - after this change; but without making this change gcc 4.6.3 cannot be used with any degree of C++11 support at all.

You have not given any reason for using such an old compiler.

Comment: Respected Sir, Can you please say me the steps how to change -std=c++11 to -std=c++0x. I am not getting how to change it.

Comment: @PrabhulingBiradar you can use the gnu text editor for editing Makefile with CFLAGS definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs